# htaccess redirect domain with query string to subdomain with excludes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have moved our site to a subdomain while on the main domain we have a new site with new url's. What we are trying to do is having the old url's redirect to the subdomain while the excluding the new url's.

here's examples of the old url's:

http://www.domain.co.il/index.php?dir=app_admin&page=ip_stat&op=list&pos=0

should be redirected to:

http://sub.domain.co.il/index.php?dir=app_admin&page=ip_stat&op=list&pos=0

While the new site url's (do not contain php) and the homepage should not be effected.

This is what our htaccess looks like:

It does redirect the url's to the sub, but does not exclude the new pages and redirect them to the subdomain home (sub.domain.com)

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !contact(|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !about(|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Hopefully someone can help us get this right, we get many 404 in our gwt now :/

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix some regex and reorder your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(contact|about) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also test this in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, thanks for you help!
Your code redirects everything to the subdomain and not ignoring the pages.

Comment: it seems to work now but I realized it redirects the new site css and js files making it to not load properly :/  I was trying to write a rule that redirects only if url contains php but couldn't get it to take effect.
I answered my question with the code I have at the moment

Comment: Much better, everything loads now, but home page is redirecting to subdomain. Perhaps my other approach is better? by redirecting only if url contains php (I just got it to work!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code for the site.
The way things are set up is that the new site is being called from a folder named "main" while the old site is being called from the root directory.
So we actually have 2 htaccess.

Here's the root htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/([^.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]     

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin$ index.php?dir=app_misc&page=login [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ index.php?dir=app_misc&page=login [L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots.php [L]

RewriteRule ^adv$ adv/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^adv/$ adv/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(([0-9]+)_([^/]+)|([0-9]+))$
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php?a=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

and the htaccess in the "main" folder:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(contact|about) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

I've tested on few browsers and in incognito mode as well

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of excluding urls which caused necessary css & js files to redirect as well, I solved it by creating a redirect that effect only url's with php.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```